# Failed to create parent directory 'C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Android Studio\.gradle' LibGDX

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, libgdx

I am using LibGDX to run an app an my pc. As of right now only the android app configuration works... Here is an example of what happens when I run the Gradle task "desktop:run"

```
'desktop:run'...


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
    Could not create service of type ScriptPluginFactory using BuildScopeServices.createScriptPluginFactory().
> Could not create service of type CrossBuildFileHashCache using BuildSessionScopeServices.createCrossBuildFileHashCache().

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED in 1s
Failed to create parent directory 'C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Android Studio\.gradle' when creating directory 'C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Android Studio\.gradle\4.0\fileHashes'
Task execution finished 'desktop:run'.
```

I think this may be because I am not running android studio as an administrator, but I don't know how to do that. I have already tried manually creating the .gradle folder (but Windows won't let me do that) and reinstalling android studio but there is no difference.

Comment: try to run Android Studio as admin

Comment: @Aryan How? Any Tips?

Comment: As I see you're working on Windows ? Left click on `Android Studio` icon, choose `run as Admin` from popup.

Comment: Ok. I'll try that, @Aryan